# Cannot reference monotouch.dll when using SQLCipher?

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.ios, sqlcipher

I have a Xamarin iOS project where I have just added SQLCipher to my packages. I now get a build error saying:

```
iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT0034: Cannot reference 'monotouch.dll' in a 
Xamarin.iOS project - it is implicitly referenced by 
'SQLite.Net.Platform.SQLCipher.XamarinIOS, Version=4.1.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (MT0034) (myProject.iOS)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I have tried deleting the sqlcipher package and adding again, rebuilding, and restarting Xamarin but no luck. Thanks for any help

Comment: Monotouch is the older 32 bit version of the library.  The new 32/64 bit versions are XamarinIOS.  It sounds like this version of SQLCipher may be referencing the old 32 bit only version.

Comment: @Jason so would that mean I need a new sqlcipher reference?

Comment: Either you're using an old version, or they haven't updated to support x64.  I would contact their support